# Computing conditional SLOPE

Tags: excel

I have a simple spreadsheet, where column A is a bunch of dates (ascending) and column B is a bunch of values. Finding the OLS slope is easy:

```
SLOPE(B2:B161,A2:A161)
```

But I don't want the slope of everything. I want to see the slope for each month. So if C3 is "3", I'd want to do something like:

```
SLOPE(IF(MONTH(A2:A161)==C3,B2:B161), A2:A161)
```

Which is wrong, but hopefully conveys what I'm trying to do. How do I actually do this?

Comment: I'm not sure why the equals sign is repeated in your attempt. Without that duplication, and properly entered as an array formula**, that should work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea more or less.  Try the following, but instead of just pressing enter to commit the value to the cell, press Control+Shift+Enter (CSE) which turns it into an array formula and makes it behave the way you'd like.

```
=SLOPE(IF(MONTH(A2:A161)=3,A2:A161),B2:B161)
```