# Slope calculation with multiple conditions

Tags: excel

I'm trying to calculate the slope of values by month beyond a year (it would be simple if I could do slope in a pivot but that doesn't seem possible).

I have a date column, which goes beyond one year (A), and a value column (B). C2 gives the year I want (2014 in this case), and D2 gives the month as an integer (1 in this case, for January). I would go by month up till present if I can get it to work for one month.

I am essentially trying to do what was solved here:
[Computing conditional SLOPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933102/computing-conditional-slope)  but by also adding a year condition:

When I do an IF(AND..) the formula seems to fall over. I'm using:

```
{=SLOPE(IF(AND(YEAR(A2:A161)=C2,MONTH(A2:A161)=D2),B2:B161),A2:A161)}
```

as an array formula. Am I not able to nest conditions within a slope calculation or have I made a mistake in the formula?

Apologies if I've misphrased something or missed a relevant answer (I did check) this is my first post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use AND() in an array formula. Instead you must nest multiple IF statements. Try this:

```
=SLOPE(IF(YEAR(A2:A161)=C2,IF(MONTH(A2:A161)=D2,B2:B161)),A2:A161)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could multiply the conditions (to keep it a bit cleaner):

=SLOPE(IF((YEAR(A2:A161)=C2)*(MONTH(A2:A161)=D2))=1,B2:B161,A2:A161)